# Promotion to BigDecimal doesn't happen

Tags: clojure

I'm using Clojure 1.5.1. Here is my program:

```
(def bricks4
  (memoize (fn [n]
             (cond (> 0 n) 0
                   (= 0 n) 1
                   (= 1 n) 1
                   :else (+ (bricks4 (- n 1))
                            (bricks4 (- n 2))
                            (bricks4 (- n 3))
                            (bricks4 (- n 4)))))))
```

(bricks4 70) throws exception:

```
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

I'm confused, because I thought Clojure will automatically promote numbers from Integer to Long and then to BigDemical.

What should I do to fix this program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clojure hasn't auto-promoted to bigint since 1.2, which is like...three years ago? These days the default is for better performance, but you can get the auto-promoting behavior by using `+'` instead of `+`, `*'` instead of `*`, and so on.